# Issues using the scipy.sparse.linalg linear system solvers

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I've got linear system to solve which consists of large, sparse matrices.

I've been using the `scipy.sparse` library, and its `linalg` sub-library to do this, but I can't get some of the linear solvers to work.

Here is a working example which reproduces the issue for me:

```
from numpy.random import random
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve, minres

N = 10
A = csc_matrix( random(size = (N,N)) )
A = (A.T).dot(A) # force the matrix to be symmetric, as required by minres
x = csc_matrix( random(size = (N,1)) ) # create a solution vector
b = A.dot(x) # create the RHS vector

# verify shapes and types are correct
print('A', A.shape, type(A))
print('x', x.shape, type(x))
print('b', b.shape, type(b))

# spsolve function works fine
sol1 = spsolve(A, b)

# other solvers throw a incompatible dimensions ValueError
sol2 = minres(A, b)
```

Running this produces the following error

```
    raise ValueError('A and b have incompatible dimensions')
ValueError: A and b have incompatible dimensions
```

for the call to `minres`, even though the dimensions clearly *are* compatible. Other solvers in `scipy.sparse.linalg`, such as `cg`, `lsqr` and `gmres` all throw an identical error.

This is being run on python 3.6.1 with SciPy 0.19.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage is incompatible with the API!

[spsolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve) on `b`:

> b : ndarray or sparse matrix
>
> The matrix or vector representing the right hand side of the equation. If a vector, b.shape must be (n,) or (n, 1).

**sparse b is allowed**

[minres](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.minres.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.minres) on `b`:

> b : {array, matrix}
>
> Right hand side of the linear system. Has shape (N,) or (N,1).

**sparse b is not allowed here!**

The same applies to the mentioned non-working solvers (where lsqr might be a bit different -> array_like vs. array).

This is not that uncommon as sparse rhs-vectors are not helping in many cases and a lot of numerical-optimization devs therefore drop support!

This works:

```
sol2 = minres(A, b.todense())
```

(you got my upvote and praise for the nice reproducible example!)